# Unhandled error event with gulp uglify

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am using `gulp-uglify` and `gulp-concat` to minify and concatenate my js files as follows:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src([
            './development/assets/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/foundation.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular.min.js.map',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-animate.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-sanitize.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/loading-bar.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-sanitize.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/toastr.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-datepicker.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angucomplete-alt.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/d3.v3.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/mm-foundation.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/ng-text-truncate.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-lazy-loader.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/jquery.tagcanvas.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-touch.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/slick.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-slick.min.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/d3.tip.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/angular-pageslide-directive.js',
            './development/assets/js/app.js',
            './development/assets/js/lib/upload.js',
            './development/assets/js/controllers/**/*.js',
            './development/assets/js/services/**/*.js',
            './development/assets/js/filters/**/*.js',
            './development/assets/js/directives/**/*.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('production.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./production/assets'))
})
```

However, when I run `gulp scripts` I get an error. This is the error stack trace:

```
events.js:85
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                ^
    Error
        at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1526:18)
        at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1534:11)
        at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2025:9)
        at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2033:9)
        at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2039:9)
        at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2059:43)
        at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2239:73)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2092:47)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2072:24)
        at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (/home/project/static/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2352:20)
```

Any idea whats going wrong? Gulp version is 3.9.0 and the node version is 0.12.7.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was caused by `'./development/assets/js/lib/angular.min.js.map'`. `uglify` cannot handle map files.

Comment: You could try logging the error cause with the help of the `gulp-util` module, for example: `uglify().on('error', gutil.log)` instead of `uglify()`.  It still logs quite long stack trace, but the error message should be in front of it.